# How to select first and last child of this table?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-table

```
<div class="showtable-page">
    <table class="layout display responsive-table">
        <thead>
            <tr><th>Show</th><th>Address</th><th>Location</th><th>Dates &amp; Hours</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="organisationnumber">ABC</td>
                <td>
                    <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                        <li>KLM</li>
                        <li>OPQ</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
                <td>US</td>
                <td>Mon-Fri 9AM - 6PM</td>
            </tr>
```

For CSS, how do I get to table tr td:first-child, table tr th:first-child for this table?
The style sheet has a base styles for tables in general, I need to change the padding on this particular table.

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with `table tr td:first-child, table tr th:first-child`? Or do you want the first row? Then `table tr:first-child td, table tr:first-child th`

Answer (score 3):

Give `ID` to this table say `mytable`.

The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element.

Try:

HTML:

```
<table id="mytable" class="layout display responsive-table">
```

CSS:

```
#mytable th:first-child{
    /* your styles*/
}
#mytable td:first-child{
    /* your styles*/
}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6qfv/2/)

Answer (score 2):

To select the last child you need for example:

```
tr td:last-child
```

Keep in mind the `:last-child` Is CSS3. So it won't be supported in older browsers ( < IE 9)

Answer (score 0):

You have already given the answer.

This should work perfectly fine.

```
table tr td:first-child, table tr th:first-child{

}
```

Can you elaborate what is the problem in this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use class selectors, or if necessary, add an ID to the table and use that (though I tend to avoid using ID selectors in CSS).

The CSS would look like this:

```
.layout.display.responsive-table th:first-child
{
    /* your css here */
}

.layout.display.responsive-table td:first-child
{
    /* your css here */
}
```

If that doesn't work, look at [this article](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html) to figure out how to override other selectors with yours. It looks like you're using Bootstrap (from the table-responsive class) so you might need to add several items to get this working.